# Wercker S3sync not working

Tags: amazon-s3, wercker

Has anyone been able to successfully deploy code using Wercker S3Sync?  I'm finding that most of the documentation that exists is for the old version of Wercker and the new version seems to work differently.  Specifically, it appears there was a deploy step through the Wercker GUI that no longer exists.

Here is my wrecker.yml file:

```
box: ruby
build:
    steps:
deploy:
    steps:
        - s3sync:
            source_dir: app/
            key-id: $S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID
            key-secret: $S3_SECRET_KEY
            bucket-url: s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME
```

I'm able to pull from Bitbucket and successfully build.  The wercker interface shows a successfully deployment and the "store" step shows ["storing artifacts complete"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iX80.png), yet, my S3 bucket is empty.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the reason the deploy step was not being triggered.  I was calling the "build" pipeline under Application Settings->Workflows->Pipelines but did not create an additional pipeline for "deploy".  I was under the impression that wercker would run the entire contents of the wercker.yml, but it only runs the section in the wercker.yml file specified in the [Pipeline Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxh5B.png).  Silly mistake, but took me days to figure out.  I hope this helps someone else.